# Delphi bytes operations and Java

Tags: java, delphi, porting

I have this function,  in Delhpi, that calculates the CRC of a transmited message. This function should return a 2bytes CRC, but, for some messages, the CRC is 3 bytes lenght.

Here's a couple of examples:

Message 0588080168F8 --> CalculateCRC(0588080168F8,5)=083D9B (3 bytes)

Message 0588080168F0 --> CalculateCRC(0588080168F0,5)=BC93 (2 bytes)

Here is the original delphi code:

```
procedure CalculateCRC(var Message: TMessage);
var
  counter: byte;
  counter1: byte;
begin
  for counter := 1 to Message.MessageLength + 1 do
  begin
    if counter = 1 then
      Message.CRC := 0 xor (word(Message.MessageLength) shl 8)
    else
      Message.CRC := Message.CRC xor (word(Message.Data[counter-1]) shl 8);

    for counter1 := 1 to 8 do
    begin
      if (Message.CRC and $8000) = $8000 then
        Message.CRC := (Message.CRC shl 1) xor $1021
      else
        Message.CRC := Message.CRC shl 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And here's my Java function:

```
  public static byte[] calculateCRC(byte[] msg, int len)
  {
    int crc=0;

    for(int i=1; i<=len+1;i++)
    {
      if(i==1)
        crc= 0 ^ (len<<8);
      else
        crc=crc ^ ((msg[i-1] & 0xff) << 8);

      for(int j=1; j<=8;j++)
      {
        if((crc & 0x8000) == 0x8000)
          crc= (crc <<1 ) ^ 0x1021;
        else
          crc= (crc <<1 ) ;
      }
    }

    return new byte[] {(byte)((crc >>16) & 0xff),(byte) ((crc>>8) & 0xff),(byte)(crc & 0xff)};
  }
```

With this method I convert the HEX string in a byte array:

```
  private static byte[] hexToBytes(String s) 
  {
   int len = s.length();
   byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
   {
    data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
   }
   return data;
  }
```

My code works to 2 bytes CRCs but fails to give the correct CRC on 3 bytes messages...
Any help or ideas?
Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: Always use the curly brackets with `if` and `else`, even if you only want a single operation. It will increase the readability of your code and possibly fix your current error. Based on your code formatting, I guess you expect other behavior from your code.

Comment: can you post sample i/p and o/p and expected results ?

Comment: From what you say I can't tell if it's the origin of your problem, but be careful that in Java, byte is signed, when in Delphi it is unsigned.

Comment: @AmandeepJiddewar The expected result is on my post. For the first message (with the 3 bytes CRC) my function return FB3D9B when it should return 083D9B.

Comment: Can you verify that the delphi version returns `083D9B` (what you want java to return) and not `FB3D9B` (what java returns).

Comment: What is the definition of `Message.CRC`? - also, Delphi's `for i := m to n` is equivalent to Java's `for (i = m; i <= n; i++)` (less or equal than) so you may be reading one byte (or char) past the end of your data

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: (From the delphi code) CRC: word;

Comment: @jlordo:I'm afraid I cant compile the delphi code, but I know that 083D9B is the correct answer.

Comment: @Pedro: If you're not **100% sure** of that, you're wasting our time... As of right now, I think the java code is right, and you're expecting the wrong output (based on uncheckable facts).

Comment: @jlordo: You could be right, of course, but I know that that CRC is the correct one, because I have a phisical device connected to my computer, throug a comm port, and I know that the device is sending that message because I'm monitoring the serial port, so I can "read" the correct CRC...

Comment: @Pedro: Why are you passing len = 5 for a byte array containig 6 bytes??

Comment: @Pedro: And the output of your method for the 2 byte example is also 3 bytes... As Cyrille Karmann pointed out, the java version never looks at the first byte passed, I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @jlordo:Because the original delphi method uses len+1 in the for next cycle. I have been thinking in your previous comment and I think that you could be right. I don't have all the data to say with 100% sure that the CRC function should return that value. What I know is that the device actually sends that message, with that CRC code... Maybe I'm really wasting everybody's time...

Comment: @jlordo:I know about the 2 bytes message. I intended to use a test clause to check if the CRC was 2 or 3 bytes long, before returning the array. I would use return new byte[] {(byte)((byte) ((crc>>8) & 0xff),(byte)(crc & 0xff)}; instead.

Comment: Pedro, what's what you really want? To fix your Java code, or to fix your Delphi code? (BTW, that Delphi code cannot possibly return a 3 byte value if `CRC` is defined as `word`.)

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: I was trying to port the Delhpi method to Java... but from all your comments, I now think that the problem must be elsewhere... But at least I know that the Delphi method was ported correctly to Java.

Answer (score 2):

In this part of your Delphi code:

```
for counter := 1 to Message.MessageLength + 1 do
  begin
    if counter = 1 then
      Message.CRC := 0 xor (word(Message.MessageLength) shl 8)
    else
      Message.CRC := Message.CRC xor (word(Message.Data[counter-1]) shl 8);
```

You are counting from 1 to MessageLength+1. And the logic seems to imply that the first index in Message.Data is 1. So I guess this code is based on the fact that String indexes in Delphi starts at 1. But in Java it is not so, they start at 0. So you should probably rewrite your Java method this way:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            crc = 0 ^ (len << 8);
        else
            crc = crc ^ ((msg[i - 1] & 0xff) << 8);
```

Comment: This suggestion changed the method result from 083D9B to F34F93! :) The correct answer is 083D9B. Thanks

Comment: @Pedro: Based on this comment your current result and the correct result are the same. Is your problem solved?

Comment: How are you using this method? I am trying `byte bytes[] = { 0x05, (byte) 0x88, 0x08, 0x01, 0x68, (byte) 0xF8 }; byte[] calculateCRC = calculateCRC(bytes, bytes.length);`. Is that what you do?

Comment: @jlordo: Sorry, my mistake. The method returns FB3D9B, and with the suggested change, returns F34F93 and the correct CRC is 083D9B. Uff!

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann: No, 0588080168F8 is an Hex string. I convert it to a byte array first. Please, see my edited post.